# jQuery click function doesn't do what I want

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table made up with `DataTables`.

I wrote this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabletest tbody td').click( function () {
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos[0],null,true);
  });

  var oTable = $('#tabletest').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bLengthChange": false, 
    "bFilter": true
  });
});
```

This makes it possible to delete a row in the DataTable. It works.

With the tbody call it deletes a row simply when you click anywhere in a row. 
What I want is, that it only works when I click on a delete button I've made (with an ID).

Do you guys have a solution?

I made the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tabletest tbody td .delete').click( function () {
var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parent() );
oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos[0],null,true);
});

var oTable = $('#tabletest').dataTable( {
"bPaginate": true,"sPaginationType": "full_numbers","bAutoWidth":    
false,"bLengthChange": false, "bFilter": true   } );
} );
```

And HTML button in the DataTables table:

```
     <tr>
        <td>{{ record.EventDate |date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.EventName }}</td>
        <td><a href="editevent/{{ record.Id }}"><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/560/fast_icon_users/128/edit_user.png" class="edit"></a></td>
        <td><a href="publishevent/{{ record.Id }}"><img src="../assets/img/published.jpg" class="edit"></a></td>
        <td><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1262/amora/256/delete.png" class="edit" button class='delete'></td>
      </tr>
```

It doesn't work though. It doesn't delete anything anymore.

Comment: It would be a good idea to also provide your html.

Comment: Well, currently you're targeting entire `<td>` elements: `$('#tabletest tbody td')`  If you want to target a different element, change your jQuery selector to target that element instead.

Comment: Don't use an ID for the button as IDs should be unique across the whole document.  Instead, use a class and target that (as per @Shiladitya 's answer, just adding why you'd use a class not an ID).

Answer (score 0):

Just give the button a class, for example  `<button class='delBtn'>Delete</button>`

And change your click event to:

```
$('#tabletest tbody td .delBtn').click( function () {
  var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parent() );
  oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos[0],null,true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! See my edit. It doesn't function anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).parent() );

Comment: or $(this).parent().parent()

Comment: Then would you please share all your HTML

Comment: I copied it into the first post. It's Twig HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#tabletest").on("click", ".delete", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();    
   return false;
  });
```

Comment: Is there an error when you try it?  Are you sure you have the right selectors?

Comment: There is no error. It is just no clickable at all.
What do you mean with the right selectors?

Comment: The table id and button class

Comment: The table id=tabletest. The button id is in the code above.